# Get variable from previous blog while using switch_to_blog

Tags: multisite, globals, switch-to-blog

I'm writing a query that switches to the main blog of a MU site using switch_to_blog(). All is well except i'm attempting to write a wp_query that includes a variable needed from the previous blog. All the content being pulled from the main blog is stored in a CPT with a taxonomy that corresponds to the various sub-blog names. I'm attempting to store bloginfo('name'); from my previous blog, and pull it into the query after switch_to_blog, but for obvious reasons, no luck (it gets the current bloginfo, not the previous.) Is there any way either to save the the previous bloginfo into a global of some sort, or to switch back to the previous blog just to get that variable mid-query?

See my query below for better illustration:

```
$location = bloginfo('name'); 
   switch_to_blog( 1 );

    $the_query = new WP_Query(  array(
        'post_type' => 'staff', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'tax_query' => array( 
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'location',  // name of tax
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $location, // this doesn't work, returns nothing
            ),
        ),
    ) ); ?>

  <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php   restore_current_blog(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code, which I assume is in a function, should pass variables needed from the current blog. So, assuming that your code in your question is called by `somefunction()`, change that to pass along variables from the current blog, as in

```
// variables from the current blog
$current_blog_1 = "some value"
$current_blog_2 = "another value"
// do the code in the original question
somefunction ($current_blog_1, $current_blog_2);
```

It might even be more efficient to put current_blog values in an array, as in

```
// set some values before you call your code via a function
$current_blog_array = array();
$current_blog_array[] = "some value";
$current_blog_array[] = "another value";
// call the function with an array, empty if needed
somefunction ($current_blog_array = array());
```

Then process the array values in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

`bloginfo()` echos, not returns, so it doesn't work to use it to save into the `$location` variable. Use `get_bloginfo()` instead and it should work to get the info from the site that calls your code.